# configure pacemaker for galera

Tags: pacemaker, galera

I have a galera / mariaDB cluster of two nodes on two remote sites that works perfectly.

I want to set up a solution that would pause one of the two servers / node if the ping to an external IP was KO, then restart the same server as soon as the external IP is reachable again.

I imagine that with pacemaker it must be feasible.